# JavaScript: Is it worth making variables private and defining getters/setters?

Tags: javascript, oop, class, coding-style, web-standards

I'd like to start by saying that I understand that JavaScript is a Classless language.  My background is in Java, C++, and Objective-C which are all classic OOP languages that support Classes.

I'm expanding into Web Development and have been experimenting with JavaScript and learning its Patterns.  Right now I'm working with the Constructor Pattern that simulates  Classes with in JavaScript.

So this is my "practice" class:

```
function Car( model, year, miles ) {
    this.model = model;
    this.year = year;
    this.miles = miles;

    var privateVarTest = 10;

    this.getPrivateVarTest = function() {
        return privateVarTest;
    }

    this.setPrivateVarTest = function( value ) {
        privateVarTest = value;
    }
}

Car.prototype.toString = function() {
    return this.model + " is a " + this.year + " model and has " + 
           this.miles + " miles.";
}

var myCar = new Car( "Ford Focus", "2006", "65,000" );
document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML += '</br> Testing </br>';
document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML += myCar.toString() + '</br>';
document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML += myCar.model + '</br>';
document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML += myCar.getPrivateVarTest() + '</br>';
myCar.setPrivateVarTest( 20 );
document.getElementById('notepad').innerHTML += myCar.getPrivateVarTest() + '</br>';
```

Now I like using the `prototype` way of defining functions, as it doesn't instantiate a new version of the function for each `Car` Object created.  However, in classic OOP languages we make our variables `private` and create `public` functions/methods to set and get these variables as needed.

JavaScript being Classless there is no `private` or `public` key word for this use, so I thought I'd experiment with a method of "faking" a `private` variable, and that's when found that using `var` instead of `this` essential makes it unaccessible out side of the `constructor`, but I was able to define getters and setters that would allow me to.

Now finaly to my question, sorry about the long wind up. For Best Practices from experinced JavaScript programmers, would you make all variables `private` to follow the standards of other OOP languages, and set getters and setter (which can not be prototyped forcing a creation for each Object), or avoid them as much as possible since the `this` keyword basicly lets you get and set all you want, and ONLY use `private` for hard coding some internal data needed for the class?

Thank you for taking the time to read this and providing to the discussion, I'm really just trying to get a feel for the standards that are used as Best Practices by experinced Web Developers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**General OOP**

I'm in the camp that getters and setters are largely completely pointless and silly regardless of what language you're writing code in.

For the most part, exposed properties should be rare since any property of an object should typically be within the object's domain so only the object should actually change its own internals as a side-effect of other actions, not because some other object directly told it to change something. There are exceptions I'm sure (there always are) but I can't remember the last time I needed to make one.

Furthermore, when properties are exposed, the only reason to expose with a method is because you either can't just expose the property due to language constraints (Java) or because some validation or notification has to happen when you change that property. Just tacking on methods Java-bean-style that do nothing more than actually alter or return properties does nothing to preserve encapsulation. You might as well just make the property public if you can.

But the real problem with wanting to get/set everything willy-nilly from all over the place is that you've basically just written chained procedural code and called it OOP. You still have a long winding series of things that can only be reasoned about in terms of one happening after the other. With OOP, the idea is to avoid that long winding spaghetti chain so you can view your architecture more from the perspective of larger constructs that own specific domains interacting with each other at key points. Without that, you're perhaps reducing the spaghetti a touch by at least categorizing your functions under namespaces so it's easier to know where to look for stuff but you're not really leveraging the key wins that OOP can provide your architecture.

The real value of private or in JS's case local constructor/factory-closur vars is signalling intent. If it's exposed, something external really should be changing it. If it isn't, then you've made it clear that the var is only the object's business.

**JS OOP**

My advice is to forget class-emulation in JS. It's completely unnecessary. Prototypes are elegant and easy once you understand them. Think of a constructor's prototype property as a kind of a backup object. If you call a method on an instance that it doesn't have, the next step is to check the instance's constructor's prototype object property. If that object doesn't have it, then its constructor's prototype object gets checked and so on until you finally reach the core Object constructor's prototype.

It's because of that lookup process that you can add new methods to a constructor on the fly and have all instances "inherit" it after they've been built but it's not really inheritance so much as a fallback process.

Inheritance in JS is stupid-easy. That doesn't mean you should do a ton of it though. Long chains of cascading inheritance is regarded as an anti-pattern in any language for good reason and due to the way the callback process works, it can also really kill perf if you're hammering on the call object through like 18 levels of prototypes for every little thing in JS. I would say prefer composite objects to inheritance and when inheritances seems like a wiser option, check yourself any time you're tempted to inherit through more than 2-3 prototype links in the chain.

Oh, and one JS gotcha to look out for on local instance vars in the constructors as private properties: that's just JS's closure rules within a function scope context in action really. Methods declared in the prototype or outside of the constructor function can't access those internal vars. Constructor functions invoked with the new keyword change the rules of what 'this' accesses and they leave an instance behind but are otherwise executed JS functions in every other way.

Other flavors of crazy but also crazy-powerful worth understanding in JS OOP are the apply, call, and now bind methods. I tend to see these more as things you'd want in a factory but they are very powerful.

Once you've mastered JS OOP, start understanding JS from a functional perspective and you'll discover it has a really powerful 1-2 punch combo going on. We can do just about anything very easily and with a minimum of code in JS. The design tradeoff is performance (which modern JIT compilers are handling surprisingly well) and that it gives you plenty of rope to hang yourself with. I prefer the rope. The self-lynching is no fun but that's part of the learning/developing better instincts process which happens much faster as a result and leads to more maintainable code in the long haul. Whereas Java basically forces OOP implementation but due to being overly protectionist in regards to devs doing dumb things to themselves, results in community wide adoption of practices that run completely counter to the whole point of OOP.

**The short version:**

- Stop getting/setting a lot if you do, regardless of language. It drastically reduces the win factor of implementing OOP in the first place.
- Prototypes are really simple, elegant, and powerful. Tinker with them. Learn them. But be warned. Classes might start to feel archaic, clumsy, and overwrought in comparison (although to be fair, completely necessary in non-interpreted languages).
- To make JS work well for you, self-learn the crap out of whatever aspect of it you happen to be dealing with. The rewards in terms of raw elegant linguistic power are more than worth the time spent. JS is closer to Scheme than the languages you listed being familiar with so it's weird but it's not being weird arbitrarily or without design principles in mind and JS's dominating success in web UI is no accident, regardless of what people telling everybody we're "stuck with it" would have you believe.
- Full disclosure: I don't love Java.

Update:

The es6 class keyword changes virtually nothing about OOP in JS. It's 100% syntax-sugar. IMO, the use of the word "class" isn't doing newcomers any favors but there are advantages/disadvantages to all three styles of object constructor/creation and object instantiation in JS and they're all worth knowing/understanding. Those three approaches are functions as constructors, Object.create, and now the class keyword.

Comment: Thank you Erik for that very well thought out and constructed answer!  I've recently started developing in the Web arena with the normal languages, PHP, HTML, XML, SQL (for data storage and retrieval), and of course JavaScript.  I initially only used JavaScript as a last resort, but I am noticing a lot of power in JavaScript (especially with jQuery) to accomplish some really nice applications.  Thanks again Erik!

Comment: jQuery is powerful at reducing/normalizing DOM API cruft but I try to bury it inside objects with interfaces more accessible to non-UI-specialized web devs. When you get a chance, try understanding how it works under the hood. It looks like a mess at first but there's some really smart stuff going on there from a JavaScript object factory perspective in terms of keeping the objects lightweight. I would definitely prefer JSON to XML any time you have a choice of data formats. JSON is much more compact and it's JavaScript so easy to read/use on the client.

Answer (score 1):

We need to be aware of our tendency to want every new language we learn to behave identically to the last language we learned.  Or the first.  And so forth.  Douglas Crockford has a [great (albeit a bit dated) google talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook), in which he muses, "Javascript is the only language I know of that people feel they don't need to learn before using it".  That talk will answer a lot of questions you never knew you had, including the one you've asked here.

There's nothing wrong with writing setters and getters.  There's rarely harm in doing work to keep one's own sanity.  You will happen to have a 'C accent' when speaking JS, but at least you'll be clear in your intent to anyone reading your code.

My sanity saving tip for managing 'this' across scopes, always remember that you can save your current 'this' before entering a new context:

```
var self = this;
```

I avoid using prototype except in special cases by including my object methods within the scope of the declaration.

```
function MyClass(_arg){
    var self = this;
    this.arg = _arg;

    this.returnArg = function(){
         return self.arg; 
    }
}

var foo = new MyClass("bar");
foo.returnArg();  //"bar"
```

Comment: So I see how saving a reference to the original `this` could be usefull, but how does this help encapsulate data and prevent access to certain aspects of the Class?  Do you and other JavaScript programmers not worry about limiting data access when using Classes?

Comment: Encapsulation isn't about limiting data access, it's about binding domain data such that only the object itself should be making the decision to change anything. That's my fundamental issue with wholesale getting/setting. Ideally, in most cases, objects make requests of each other to do things. They don't tell each other what to do with their internal data.

Comment: ^I should elaborate. Limiting of data access does effectively happen. Just learn to see that as a side effect and not the goal in order to grok OOP. People get their chickens and eggs crossed on that one all the time.

Comment: And I'll always +1 anybody who makes the point that JS needs to be learned as its own paradigm like any other language. I don't blame people for being fooled though. The C-syntax makes it easy to think in terms of what it can't do compared to languages that look and feel very similar several steps beyond Hello World.

Comment: My response is to highlight a C-like syntax for binding data to a domain in Javascript, as a proof of concept, and under the assumption that the question itself is aware of its own traditional OO bias.  Erik's specificity regarding the intent of encapsulation is much appreciated because it highlights that JS, while capable of mimicking other language's facilities, has its own.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses.  I am indeed doing my best to learn JavaScript, hence the reasoning behind my question.  I know how things are done in one langauge, but want to JavaScript as JavaScript :-)  The main thing I'm looking at is the use of Patterns in JavaScript (from a book I'm reading) and trying to figure out the OO uses of JavaScript, or if OO is even really needed in JavaScript since really everything is an Object.

Comment: Everything being an object doesn't remove the need for OOP. Lots of design patterns aren't a perfect fit for JS since we can pass functions around but plenty are. Also, the wikipedia entry on design patterns is surprisingly good for an overview.

Answer (score 0):

in case of OOP I have to say infact javascript provide some level of oop.

by that I mean 4 main concepts of OOP design could be implemented in javascript although it is not strong and very well defined as in Java or C++. lets check those concepts and I will try to provide an example for each of them.

**1- Abstraction** : here as I said before we can understand why OOP is not very well defined as in Java, in Java we implement Abstraction concept using Classes, Variables, interfaced,... but in javascript Abstraction is rather implicitly defined in contrast to other OOP languages such as Java.

**2- Encapsulation** : I guess an example will suffice here

```
function Student (stdName, stdEmail, stdAvg) {
  this.name = theName;
  this.email = theEmail;
  this.avg = stdAvg;
 }
```

here also as you see we define a "class" like concept using functions in fact if get type Student you'll see it is a function.

**3,4 - Inheritance and Polymorphism** : 
the way that JavaScript achieves Inheritance and Polymorphism is different than Java or C++ because of its prototypial (to be honest I have no idea any other way to say that) approach.

```
const Gun = function(soundEffect){
  this.soundEffect = soundEffect;
};

Gun.prototype.fire = function(){
  console.log(this.soundEffect);
};

const DesertEagle = function(color,clipSize){
  this.color = color;
  this.clipSize = clipSize;
};

DesertEagle.prototype = new Gun("pew pew peeeew");

const myWeapon = new DesertEagle("black",15);

myWeapon.fire();
```

now in order to cover the public/private access for variables and functions we have to use some kind of technique to implement such concept. check the code below:

```
const Student = function(name, stdNumber, avg){
  this.name = name;
  this.stdNumber = stdNumber;
  this.avg = avg;
  var that = this; //NOTE : we need to store a reference to "this" in order for further calls to private members

  this.publicAccess = { // a set of functions and variables that we want as public
    describe: function () {
       console.log(that.name + " : " + that.stdNumber);
    },
    avg: this.avg,
  };

  return this.publicAccess; // return set of public access members
};


const newStd = new Student("john", "123", "3.4");

newStd.describe();
// output: john : 123
console.log(newStd.avg)
// output: 3.4
```

in ES6 defining a class is mush easier but it is just syntax sugar it is still the same thing at the heart of it.

I hope it will help . 
I also recommend you this article ([Javascript design patterns](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript)) it will provide some helpful information about avascript capabilities and design patterns.

please accept my apology for my poor English.